# Solving equation for integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to prove that the only $n\in\mathbb{N}⁺$ such that there is an $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{2m}$ is 3 and 6. I don't even know how to start! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\cos\frac {2\pi}n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ whereas $|\frac1{2m}|\le \frac12$. Hence you need only test a few initial cases.

Comment: Expanding on Hagen von Eitzen's comment. For $n=1$ and $n=2$ and $n=4$ then $\frac {2\pi}n$ will be on the border of quadrants.  $n=3$ is a solution.  For $n \ge 5$ then $\frac{2\pi}n$ will be in the first quadrant and the angle will be getting smaller and the cos will be getting larger.  As $n=6$ yield $1/2$ then $n > 7$ yield $\cos > 1/2 \ne 1/2m$.  So $n=6$ is a maximum.  That leaves only $n= 5$ to test.

Comment: I do feel there must be something slicker I am missing.  Something about expressing the $\arccos \frac{\theta}2$ in terms of $\theta$ or $\cos (n*\theta)$ explicitely written out... but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

The initial values for small $n$ fall on the cosine graph as follows:

[image]

This suggests that you demonstrate that for $k>6,$ $\cos\frac{2\pi}{k}>\frac 12$ and then identify the valid points in the remaining options.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_n(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We have:
$$ p_1(x)=x-1,\quad p_2(x)=x+1,\quad p_3(x)=2x+1,\quad p_4(x)=x$$
$$ p_5(x)=4x^2+2x-1,\quad p_6(x)=2x-1,\quad p_7(x)=8x^3+4x^2-4x-1. $$
By Galois Theory, for any $n>2$ the degree of $p_n(x)$ is given by $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}$ and $p_n(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $p_n(x)$ may have a rational root only if $n\leq 2$ or $\varphi(n)\leq 2$.
Since $\varphi(n)>2$ for any $n\geq 7$, it is enough to inspect the above cases to deduce the claim.

With a similar approach one may prove much more:

> If $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and
>   $\cos\left(2\pi\frac{p}{q}\right)\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $q\mid 6$ and
>   $2\cos\left(2\pi\frac{p}{q}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}$.